# How can I call components function from js function?

Tags: reactjs

I need to call this.props.updateDisplay() from receiveEvent() function. I do not understand how to do it or if it is even possible.

I have tried to position updateDisplay itno constant but it didnot work.

The problem is that the receveEvent is called before the component is rendered. And the function to render it is this.props.updateDisplay(). Maybe there is some way to pass updateDisplay function from parent component to receive event?

```
export function recieveEvent(node) {
currNode = node;
heading = node.data.heading;
if (node.selected === true){
    console.log("displayWidget")
}
```

}

```
export class WidgetForCondition extends React.Component {

state = {
    helper: false,
    operators: ["=", ">", "<"],
    chosenOperator: null,
};

handleChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({chosenOperator: event.target.value})
};

handleHeading = (e) => {
    this.setState({heading: e.target.value}, () => {heading = this.state.heading});
    passData(e.target.value)
};

render() {

    return (
        <TrayWidget style={{width: 1000}}>
            <List>
                <ListItem style={{color: "#FFFFFF"}}>
                    <IconButton onClick={() => this.props.updateDisplay()}>
                        <KeyboardArrowLeft style={{color: "#FFFFFF"}}/>
                    </IconButton>
                    Блок с условием
                </ListItem>
                <ListItem>
                    <TextField
                        label="Название"
                        fullWidth
                        margin="auto"
                        defaultValue={heading}
                        onChange={e => this.handleHeading(e)}
                    />
                </ListItem>
                <ListItem style={{color: "#FFFFFF"}}>
                    Условия
                    <IconButton>
                        <AddIcon style={{color: "#FFFFFF"}}/>
                    </IconButton>
                </ListItem>
                <ConditionComponent operators={this.state.operators} handleChange={this.handleChange}/>
            </List>
        </TrayWidget>
    );
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

just use a callback.

```
export function recieveEvent(node, callback) {
    currNode = node;
    heading = node.data.heading;
    if (node.selected === true){
       console.log("displayWidget")
    }
    if (typeof callback === 'function') {
        callback();
    }
}
```

In you component pass the function to `recieveEvent`.

```
recieveEvent(node, this.props.updateDisplay);
```

If you use `this` within `recieveEvent` you need to bind context too.

```
recieveEvent(node, this.props.updateDisplay.bind(this));
```

If you have no possibility to pass the function like this, you have to move it to a separate file, import it and call it independently.